# Odd and Even Rows for a table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a table that get its rows from a MYSQL database

```
<table id="table1">
<?php
// Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "asnaeb") or die (mysql_error ());
// Select database
        mysql_query("SET NAMES `utf8`"); // UTF 8 support!!
    mysql_select_db("scores") or die(mysql_error());
// SQL query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM latest";
// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 
// Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row) 
?>

<?php echo $row['Header'].""; ?>
<tr>
<td id='date'><?php echo $row['Date'].""; ?></td>
<td id='time'><?php echo $row['Time'].""; ?></td>
<td id='hometeam'><?php echo $row['HomeTeam'].""; ?></td>
<td id='score'><?php echo $row['Score'].""; ?></td>
<td id='awayteam'><?php echo $row['AwayTeam'].""; ?></td>
<td id='other'><?php echo $row['Other'].""; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } mysql_close(); ?>
</table>
```

i have 2 css class called "A" and "B" for Odd Rows and Even Rows

i currently getting this done by replacing `<tr>` with  `<tr class='<?php echo $row['Row'].""; ?>'>`  and i have in my Database table a column "Row" which i add in A or B for even or odd row... the problem is if i wanna delete or add a new row between one of these i will have to change all the A and B in the other.

I have seen in another questions many way to do that in javascript or jquery but for a normal table with TR's which is not my case...(tried some of these scripts but couldn't get it fixed)

So what i want an easier way to do that Even and Odd rows, Thanks!

Comment: use modulo operator for odd and even if(num%2==0) DO THIS else DO THAT

Comment: So many ways to do this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add those classes using jQuery easily like this

```
$(function(){
  $('#table1 tr:odd').addClass('A');

 // for even

 $('#table1 tr:even').addClass('B');

});
```

Comment: that's the best solution:) , with the pure css solution i could get it done but i had other css like hover for the rows and stuff that got messed up when added these new css... this jquery script rocks thx!

Answer (score 11):

do it in CSS way (no inline class) once and for all:

**in CSS**:

```
#table1 tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color:#ebebeb }
#table1 tr:nth-child(even) td { background-color:#0000ff }
```

**in your HTML**:

```
<table id="table1">
```

thats it, no matter if your table rows are removed/or not.

Comment: ohh I love the css3 is so powerful that scare me!

Comment: it scares me when i got into compatibility issues :)

Comment: the people who use IE don't deserve to see cool stuff of CSS3

Comment: Great and Simple Solution that's what i wanted! Thanks a lot ! :) and it work on IE9..

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you use modulo in your `while` loop ? It's a better way than store your class in your database... :

```
    $i = 0;        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 
    // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row) 
    ?>

    <?php echo $row['Header'].""; ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $i%2 == 0 ? "class_A" : "class_B" ; $i++;?>" >
    <td id='date'><?php echo $row['Date'].""; ?></td>
    <td id='time'><?php echo $row['Time'].""; ?></td>
    <td id='hometeam'><?php echo $row['HomeTeam'].""; ?></td>
    <td id='score'><?php echo $row['Score'].""; ?></td>
    <td id='awayteam'><?php echo $row['AwayTeam'].""; ?></td>
    <td id='other'><?php echo $row['Other'].""; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php } mysql_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$class="odd"
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 
  $class = ($class=='even' ? 'odd' : 'even');
?>
<tr class="<?php echo $class">
...
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, PHP, Javascript and even pure CSS. Here's the PHP way to add a class to every other row:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_blahblah()) {

$i = 0; ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $i % 2 == 0 ? 'class1' : 'class2';?>">
        <td>....</td>
    </tr>
<?php
$i++; // increment our counter 
}
```

Basically the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) returns the remainder of dividing the nubmers either side of it, so for example `3 % 2 == 1`, `4 % 2 == 0`, `5 % 2 == 1`, so we can tell if `$i` is odd or even and alternate the classes added to the `<tr>`.

IMHO you want to either do it this way for 100% guarantee it will work (no browser dependencies) or if you design your app for modern browsers go for the CSS route.