# How can I apply dynamically color to each row differently to HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created HTML table dynamically using javascripts and now I want to apply each row a different color. How can I do so?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. So, what have you tried?

Comment: Answer to your question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851816/odd-and-even-rows-for-a-table?rq=1

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
 $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

Or below

```
$(function(){
  $('#table1 tr:odd').addClass('A');

 // for even

 $('#table1 tr:even').addClass('B');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by one of the following: css OR javascript:

**javascript** approach (i suggest including jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}

// paint rows on document ready
$(function(){
    paint_rows();
});

function paint_rows() {
    $('#table_id tr').each(function(){
        $(this).css('color', get_random_color());
    });
}
</script>
```

just make sure to add enough color values into the array `colors` (can use hex values as well).

and, you can call the function `paint_rows()` whenever needed of course.

alternatively you can use **css** approach:

```
<style type="text/css">
#table_id tr:nth-child(1){color:blue;}
#table_id tr:nth-child(2){color:red;}
#table_id tr:nth-child(3){color:orange;}
/* etc... */
</style>
```

but i always prefer javascript.

**HOWEVER!**

if you just want to color **every second row** and switch between two colors (for example: one black, one blue, one black, one blue etc.) use the following **css**:

```
#table_id tr{color:black;}
#table_id tr:nth-child(even){color:blue;}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

While you build the rows assign to them a class name.
For example if you want to achieve a zebra striping  you may have a counter that increments while adding rows. Then check if the counter has odd or even value and add a class name denoting that to the corresponding row that was just added. Then in your css you can do something like,

```
.odd{
/*set background color*/
}

.even{
/*set background color*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].style.border = "1px solid red";
td1 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].style.color = "red";
td2 = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].style.color = "blue";
```

http://jsbin.com/EXUPuha/1/